# Executing a managed module for a rewritten URL in IIS7 Integrated Mode

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

In my ASP.NET app, I have two HTTP modules. One of them is used for rewriting URLs, the other is used for app-specific stuff (custom authentication .. etc). The URL-Rewriting module is executed for all requests, while the other module is only executed for managed file extensions, like .aspx

Here's how the modules are defined in web.config (note that preCondition is blank for UrlRewriteModule. This cause it to get executed for all requests):

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="MySite.UrlRewriteModule" preCondition="" />
    <add name="SiteModule" type="MySite.SiteModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

In UrlRewriteModule I use RewritePath() to rewrite some URLs (directory-like) into files with query strings. For example, from "/p/5/some-thoughts-about-the-future/" to "/post.aspx?id=5"

**Now, I was under the impression that when a URL gets rewritten, IIS7 executes the managed module (SiteModule in this case) if the new URL is for a managed extension (like .aspx). But, this doesn't seem to be the case. I noticed that SiteModule doesn't get executed for any rewritten URLs.**

Am I missing something (or doing something wrong) or is this the normal behavior in IIS7?

I came across Server.TransferRequest() which actually solves the problem (behind the scence, it involves creating a new child request). But, this can also [cause a lot of overhead](http://forums.iis.net/p/1146511/1857303.aspx) esp. under server load, and I generally prefer to avoid it.

**So, is there a way to get SiteModule to execute whenever a URL gets rewritten without using Server.TransferRequest()?**

Thanks!

Comment: My IIS 7 is creaky, but in IIS6 you could perhaps spoof this by creating a new application on the /p/ folder (even if you don't need it to exist in real life), and then turn on wildcard mapping, so that all requests in that path go to .Net. The reason to using an application on a specific sub-folder is to avoid the overhead of .Net on static requests for stuff like images and css.

Comment: Have you tried the built-in ASP.NET URL Routing? If not, I would suggest checking that out as you can have your routing done in Global.asax or an HTTP Module using Regex.